# how to stop a string with input() python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a guess the number game and I have a problem with a piece of code that is meant to stop the player from inputting a letter instead of a number.

I am trying to get a int from a player input and i can do that but when I input nothing and hit enter or a letter the value error doesn't catch it and it breaks my code

```
try:
    player_guess = input("\n\n\n{} what is your guess?\n".format(player_name)) #askes the player for a guess   
    player_guess = int(player_guess)
except ValueError as verr:
    print("please enter a number")
except Exception as ex:# do job to handle: Exception occurred while converting to int
    print("{} please only input a number.".format(player_name)) 
    time.sleep(2)
    print("\n\n\n")
    print(player_guess)
if player_guess < number_real: # if the number is lower than the real number run this
```

the last line of code is the one that breaks because I'm trying to use a string with an int.

Comment: You can't restrict what `input` takes, but you can keep asking the user until they give you a valid response

Comment: am i missing something? why don't you put the last line inside the `try:` block?